# AngularJs and jQuery UI, how to ensure no UI code in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I am using AngularJS as the framework for building a web app. The DI is good for unit testing and AnguarJS also has a best practice that not have DOM UI related code in controller. I am also using jQuery UI for building UI. Then I have a problem:

For example I am using jQuery UI dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation, so in the HTML I have the code for declaring the dialog:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
    <p>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```

Then I have a button by clicking on it the dialog will pop up

```
<a ng-click="showDialog()>Click me</a>
```

Then in the controller I have the code

```
$scope.showDialog = function() {
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog( //DOM UI code in controller!
        //...
    });
}
```

This is the basic workflow by following jQuery UI demo code: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation and I just combined it with AngularJS. It works, but I think there is a big problem in my code: I mixed DOM UI code and logic in my controller thus it breaks the test-ability of the controller.

What should I do to use jQueryUI with AngularJS without breaking DI principle and test-ability?

Answer (score 3):

That's not as easy as it may seem. Angular has so called [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) that are used to encapsulate DOM code, but writing directives isn't exactly trivial - it can be tough to get it right.

Your best bet it to use [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/) which implements *similar* functionality using bootstrap and pure angularjs (no jquery / jquery ui dependency). It doesn't try to replicate jQuery UI though, but bootstrap's JS functionality, so that's not a drop-in-replacement. I'd suggest you try finding a pure angularjs solution first, if possible.

If you *have* to use jQueryUI, you can write custom directives that delegate the actual work to jQuery UI. Here's a [datepicker example](http://www.abequar.net/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs/), and there are more examples scattered around the net. The `directive` keyword will help in googling.

If you really want to delve into the depths of writing angular directives, the source code of angular-ui is very instructive, but it requires an in-depth understanding of scopes, scope inheritance, data binding and angular's compilation process.